# How to integrate Google Distance Matrix API key in R code?

Tags: r, api, google-maps

I have registered in Google to obtain more requests of drive time distances. However Google doesn't automatically pick up this "permission" to run more than 2500 queries a day. In addition `mapdist()` doesn't have an argument to integrate an API key.

I have managed to get an API key through the Google console.

I tried to modify the raw code adding key and changing line 56, 90 & 91 as follows:

```
    mapdist <- function(from, to, mode = c("driving","walking","bicycling"),
  output = c("simple","all"), messaging = FALSE, sensor = FALSE,
  language = "en-EN", override_limit = FALSE, key = "XXXX")
{

  message("by using this function you are agreeing to the terms at :")
  message("http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/\n")

  # check parameters
  if(is.numeric(from) && length(from) == 2) from <- revgeocode(from)
  stopifnot(is.character(from))
  if(is.numeric(to) && length(to) == 2) to <- revgeocode(to)
  stopifnot(is.character(to))
  from_to_df <- data.frame(from = from, to = to, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  origins <- from_to_df$from
  destinations <- from_to_df$to # this ensures # from = # to
  mode <- match.arg(mode)
  output <- match.arg(output)
  stopifnot(is.logical(messaging))
  stopifnot(is.logical(sensor))


  getdists <- function(df){

    # format url
    origin <- df$from[1]
    origin <- gsub(",", "", origin)
    origin <- gsub(" ", "+", origin)
    origin <- paste("origins=", origin, sep = "")
    destinations <- df$to
    destinations <- gsub(",", "", destinations)
    destinations <- gsub(" ", "+", destinations)
    destinations <- paste("destinations=", paste(destinations, collapse = "|"), sep = "")
    mode4url <- paste("mode=", mode, sep = "")
    lang4url <- paste("language=", language, sep = "")
    sensor4url <- paste("sensor=", tolower(as.character(sensor)), sep = "")
    keyUrl <- paste("key=", key, sep = "")
    posturl <- paste(origin, destinations, mode4url, sensor4url, keyUrl, sep = "&")
    url_string <- paste("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?",
      posturl, sep = "")
    url_string <- URLencode(url_string)


    # check if query is too long
    if(nchar(url_string) >= 2048){
      n <- nrow(df)
      half_df <- floor(n/2)
      return(
        rbind(
          getdists(df[half_df,]),
          getdists(df[(half_df+1):n,])
        )
      )
    }

    # check/update google query limit
    check_dist_query_limit(url_string, elems = nrow(df),
      override = override_limit, messaging = messaging)


    # distance lookup
    if(messaging) message("trying url ", url_string)
    connect <- url(url_string)
    tree <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(connect), collapse = ""))
    close(connect)

    # message user
    message(paste0("Information from URL : ", url_string))

    # label destinations - first check if all were found
    if(length(df$to) != length(tree$destination_addresses)){
      message("matching was not perfect, returning what was found.")
      names( tree$rows[[c(1,1)]] ) <- tree$destination_addresses
      output <<- "all"
      # stringdist::amatch(df$to, tree$destination_addresses, maxDist = 10)
    } else {
      names( tree$rows[[c(1,1)]] ) <- df$to
    }

    # return
    tree$rows[[c(1,1)]]
  }

  out <- dlply(from_to_df, "from", getdists)

  # return all
  if(output == "all") return(out)



  # format output
  out <-
    ldply(out, function(oneFromList){
      ldply(oneFromList, function(oneToList){
        data.frame(
          m = oneToList$distance$value,
          km = oneToList$distance$value/1000,
          miles = 0.0006214 * oneToList$distance$value,
          seconds = oneToList$duration$value,
          minutes = oneToList$duration$value / 60,
          hours = oneToList$duration$value / 3600
        )
      })
    })

  names(out) <- c("from", "to", names(out)[3:ncol(out)])

  # "simple" return
  suppressMessages(join(from_to_df, out))
}




check_dist_query_limit <- function(url_string, elems, override, messaging){
  .GoogleDistQueryCount <- NULL; rm(.GoogleDistQueryCount); # R CMD check trick

  if(exists(".GoogleDistQueryCount", .GlobalEnv)){

    .GoogleDistQueryCount <<-
      subset(.GoogleDistQueryCount, time >= Sys.time() - 24*60*60)

    # 2500 per 24 hours
    if(sum(.GoogleDistQueryCount$elements) + elems > 2500){
      message("query max exceeded, see ?mapdist.  current total = ",
        sum(.GoogleDistQueryCount$elements))
      if(!override) stop("google query limit exceeded.", call. = FALSE)
    }

    # 100 per 10 seconds
    if(with(.GoogleDistQueryCount,
      sum(elements[time >= Sys.time() - 10]) + elems > 100
    )){
      if(messaging) message("waiting 10 seconds for another 100 queries...", appendLF=F)
      Sys.sleep(10) # can do better
      if(messaging) message(" done")
    }

    # append to .GoogleDistQueryCount
    .GoogleDistQueryCount <<- rbind(.GoogleDistQueryCount,
      data.frame(time = Sys.time(),  url = url_string,
        elements = elems, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    )


  } else {

    .GoogleDistQueryCount <<-
      data.frame(time = Sys.time(),  url = url_string,
        elements = elems, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  }
}



#' Check Google Maps Distance Matrix API query limit
#'
#' Check Google Maps Distance Matrix API query limit
#'
#' @return a data frame
#' @author David Kahle \email{david.kahle@@gmail.com}
#' @seealso \url{http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/}
#' @export
#' @examples
#' distQueryCheck()
distQueryCheck <- function(){
  .GoogleDistQueryCount <- NULL; rm(.GoogleDistQueryCount); # R CMD check trick
  if(exists(".GoogleDistQueryCount", .GlobalEnv)){
    remaining <- 2500-sum(
      subset(.GoogleDistQueryCount, time >= Sys.time() - 24*60*60)$elements
      )
    message(remaining, " distance queries remaining.")
  } else {
    remaining <- 2500
    message(remaining, " distance queries remaining.")
  }
  invisible(remaining)
}
```

However I got this error message when running the mapdist():

```
by using this function you are agreeing to the terms at :
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=NG17+7LG&destinations=CV2+2DX&mode=driving&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBQN9Dvgfw3bXpWj_-ddluungZcDv8Y4rg
matching was not perfect, returning what was found.
Error in `*tmp*`[[c(1, 1)]] : no such index at level 1
Called from: .fun(piece, ...)
Browse[1]> results <- dput(result)
list()
Browse[1]> res_df <- do.call(rbind, results)
```

I get the feeling that I have to integrate this key on my code on R in order for Google to pick up my "permission". I got told by a friend I could do it through `httr` but I don't know much about it.
I really don't know much about coding and I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you look at the Google API... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/ Get it working in your browser, then take that URL and use `httr::GET()`. It's probably that easy.

Comment: Hi, it seems that by changing line 92: replacing `http` by `https` helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the core code (than I run before the commmand) as follows:

```
#' Compute map distances using Google
#'
#' Compute map distances using Google Maps. Note that in most cases
#' by using this function you are agreeing to the Google Maps API
#' Terms of Service at https://developers.google.com/maps/terms.
#'
#' @param from name of origin addresses in a data frame (vector
#'   accepted)
#' @param to name of destination addresses in a data frame (vector
#'   accepted)
#' @param output amount of output
#' @param mode driving, bicycling, or walking
#' @param messaging turn messaging on/off
#' @param sensor whether or not the geocoding request comes from a
#'   device with a location sensor
#' @param language language
#' @param override_limit override the current query count
#'   (.GoogleDistQueryCount)
#' @return a data frame (output="simple") or all of the geocoded
#'   information (output="all")
#' @author David Kahle \email{david.kahle@@gmail.com}
#' @details if parameters from and to are specified as geographic
#'   coordinates, they are reverse geocoded with revgeocode.  note
#'   that the google maps api limits to 2500 element queries a day.
#' @seealso
#' \url{http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/}
#'
#' @export
#' @examples
#'
#' \dontrun{ online queries draw R CMD check times
#'
#' mapdist("waco, texas", "houston, texas")
#'
#' from <- c("houston, texas", "dallas")
#' to <- "waco, texas"
#' mapdist(from, to)
#' mapdist(from, to, mode = "bicycling")
#' mapdist(from, to, mode = "walking")
#'
#' from <- c("houston", "houston", "dallas")
#' to <- c("waco, texas", "san antonio", "houston")
#' mapdist(from, to)
#'
#'
#' # geographic coordinates are accepted as well
#' (wh <- as.numeric(geocode("the white house, dc")))
#' (lm <- as.numeric(geocode("lincoln memorial washington dc")))
#' mapdist(wh, lm, mode = "walking")
#' distQueryCheck()
#'
#' }
#'
mapdist <- function(from, to, mode = c("driving","walking","bicycling"),
  output = c("simple","all"), messaging = FALSE, sensor = FALSE,
  language = "en-EN", override_limit = FALSE, key)
{

  message("by using this function you are agreeing to the terms at :")
  message("http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/\n")

  # check parameters
  if(is.numeric(from) && length(from) == 2) from <- revgeocode(from)
  stopifnot(is.character(from))
  if(is.numeric(to) && length(to) == 2) to <- revgeocode(to)
  stopifnot(is.character(to))
  from_to_df <- data.frame(from = from, to = to, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  origins <- from_to_df$from
  destinations <- from_to_df$to # this ensures # from = # to
  mode <- match.arg(mode)
  output <- match.arg(output)
  stopifnot(is.logical(messaging))
  stopifnot(is.logical(sensor))


  getdists <- function(df){

    # format url
    origin <- df$from[1]
    origin <- gsub(",", "", origin)
    origin <- gsub(" ", "+", origin)
    origin <- paste("origins=", origin, sep = "")
    destinations <- df$to
    destinations <- gsub(",", "", destinations)
    destinations <- gsub(" ", "+", destinations)
    destinations <- paste("destinations=", paste(destinations, collapse = "|"), sep = "")
    mode4url <- paste("mode=", mode, sep = "")
    lang4url <- paste("language=", language, sep = "")
    sensor4url <- paste("sensor=", tolower(as.character(sensor)), sep = "")
    keyUrl <- paste("key=", key, sep = "")
    posturl <- paste(origin, destinations, mode4url, sensor4url, keyUrl, sep = "&")
    url_string <- paste("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?",
      posturl, sep = "")
    url_string <- URLencode(url_string)


    # check if query is too long
    if(nchar(url_string) >= 2048){
      n <- nrow(df)
      half_df <- floor(n/2)
      return(
        rbind(
          getdists(df[half_df,]),
          getdists(df[(half_df+1):n,])
        )
      )
    }

    # check/update google query limit
    check_dist_query_limit(url_string, elems = nrow(df),
      override = override_limit, messaging = messaging)


    # distance lookup
    if(messaging) message("trying url ", url_string)
    connect <- url(url_string)
    tree <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(connect), collapse = ""))
    close(connect)

    # message user
    message(paste0("Information from URL : ", url_string))

    # label destinations - first check if all were found
    if(length(df$to) != length(tree$destination_addresses)){
      message("matching was not perfect, returning what was found.")
      names( tree$rows[[c(1,1)]] ) <- tree$destination_addresses
      output <<- "all"
      # stringdist::amatch(df$to, tree$destination_addresses, maxDist = 10)
    } else {
      names( tree$rows[[c(1,1)]] ) <- df$to
    }

    # return
    tree$rows[[c(1,1)]]
  }

  out <- dlply(from_to_df, "from", getdists)

  # return all
  if(output == "all") return(out)



  # format output
  out <-
    ldply(out, function(oneFromList){
      ldply(oneFromList, function(oneToList){
        data.frame(
          m = oneToList$distance$value,
          km = oneToList$distance$value/1000,
          miles = 0.0006214 * oneToList$distance$value,
          seconds = oneToList$duration$value,
          minutes = oneToList$duration$value / 60,
          hours = oneToList$duration$value / 3600
        )
      })
    })

  names(out) <- c("from", "to", names(out)[3:ncol(out)])

  # "simple" return
  suppressMessages(join(from_to_df, out))
}




check_dist_query_limit <- function(url_string, elems, override, messaging){
  .GoogleDistQueryCount <- NULL; rm(.GoogleDistQueryCount); # R CMD check trick

  if(exists(".GoogleDistQueryCount", .GlobalEnv)){

    .GoogleDistQueryCount <<-
      subset(.GoogleDistQueryCount, time >= Sys.time() - 24*60*60)

    # 2500 per 24 hours
    if(sum(.GoogleDistQueryCount$elements) + elems > 2500){
      message("query max exceeded, see ?mapdist.  current total = ",
        sum(.GoogleDistQueryCount$elements))
      if(!override) stop("google query limit exceeded.", call. = FALSE)
    }

    # 100 per 10 seconds
    if(with(.GoogleDistQueryCount,
      sum(elements[time >= Sys.time() - 10]) + elems > 100
    )){
      if(messaging) message("waiting 10 seconds for another 100 queries...", appendLF=F)
      Sys.sleep(10) # can do better
      if(messaging) message(" done")
    }

    # append to .GoogleDistQueryCount
    .GoogleDistQueryCount <<- rbind(.GoogleDistQueryCount,
      data.frame(time = Sys.time(),  url = url_string,
        elements = elems, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    )


  } else {

    .GoogleDistQueryCount <<-
      data.frame(time = Sys.time(),  url = url_string,
        elements = elems, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  }
}



#' Check Google Maps Distance Matrix API query limit
#'
#' Check Google Maps Distance Matrix API query limit
#'
#' @return a data frame
#' @author David Kahle \email{david.kahle@@gmail.com}
#' @seealso \url{http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/}
#' @export
#' @examples
#' distQueryCheck()
distQueryCheck <- function(){
  .GoogleDistQueryCount <- NULL; rm(.GoogleDistQueryCount); # R CMD check trick
  if(exists(".GoogleDistQueryCount", .GlobalEnv)){
    remaining <- 2500-sum(
      subset(.GoogleDistQueryCount, time >= Sys.time() - 24*60*60)$elements
      )
    message(remaining, " distance queries remaining.")
  } else {
    remaining <- 2500
    message(remaining, " distance queries remaining.")
  }
  invisible(remaining)
}
```

Then I was able to modify the `mapdist()` command by adding the key name "1234" as follows:

```
# create your own 'from' and 'to' variables 
from <- drivetime$gp_postcode
to <- drivetime$h_postcode

    result <- vector("list")
    for (i in 1:nrow(drivetime)) { # could be 1:nrow(drivetime)
      result[[i]] <- mapdist(from[i], to[i], mode = "driving", override_limit = TRUE, key="1234") 
      Sys.sleep(0.5)
    }
    results <- dput(result)
    res_df <- do.call(rbind, results)
```

You can follow the number of queries made and the billing [here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?project=drivetimes-1292)

Comment: Required: library(plyr)
library(RJSONIO)

Comment: I am trying to use your code to incorporate my key in the mapdist function but I get the following:  Error in `*tmp*`[[c(1, 1)]] : no such index at level 1 .... any idea why this is?

Comment: @Estefy, I assume there must be  a problem with your postocdes/longlat. I found that sometimes `mapdist` is very arbitrary and re-running the errors by themselves don't pose a problem anymore (most of the time). Wrap your `mapdist` with `try` as follows `result[[i]] <- try(mapdist(from[i], to[i], mode = "driving", override_limit = TRUE, key="1234"), silent = FALSE)`. It will keep running despite errors and you'll see the errors in the resulting data frame. Then you can merge (on Stata for eg) to match those that have been identified, the rest will be the "errors"

Answer (score 2):

I've written the package [**googleway**](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) to access google maps API where you can specify your token key

```
For example

library(googleway)
key <- "your_api_key"

google_distance(origins = list("houston", "Dallas"),
                destinations = list("waco, Texas", "San Antonio"),
                key = key,
                simplify = FALSE)  ## use simplify = T to simplify to a data.frame


[1] "{"                                                                              
[2] "   \"destination_addresses\" : [ \"Waco, TX, USA\", \"San Antonio, TX, USA\" ],"
[3] "   \"origin_addresses\" : [ \"Houston, TX, USA\", \"Dallas, TX, USA\" ],"       
[4] "   \"rows\" : ["                                                                
[5] "      {"                                                                        
[6] "         \"elements\" : ["                                                      
[7] "            {"                                                                  
[8] "               \"distance\" : {"                                                
[9] "                  \"text\" : \"299 km\","                                       
[10] "                  \"value\" : 298585"                                           
[11] "               },"                                                              
[12] "               \"duration\" : {"                                                
[13] "                  \"text\" : \"2 hours 51 mins\","                              
[14] "                  \"value\" : 10244"                                            
[15] "               },"                                                              
[16] "               \"duration_in_traffic\" : {"                                     
[17] "                  \"text\" : \"2 hours 52 mins\","                              
[18] "                  \"value\" : 10343"                                            
[19] "               },"                                                              
[20] "               \"status\" : \"OK\""                                             
[21] "            },"
... etc
```