# Mapdist with departure_time: Invalid request

Tags: r, google-maps

I tried to edit the code of @pdx (in the question [How to integrate Google Distance Matrix API key in R code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936878/how-to-integrate-google-distance-matrix-api-key-in-r-code/37163518?noredirect=1#comment62155804_37163518) ) in order to include `traffic_mode` and `departure_time`.

The error I get is the following:

> Invalid request. Missing the 'departure_time' parameter.

This is the code:

```
#' Compute map distances using Google
#'
#' Compute map distances using Google Maps. Note that in most cases
#' by using this function you are agreeing to the Google Maps API
#' Terms of Service at https://developers.google.com/maps/terms.
#'
#' @param from name of origin addresses in a data frame (vector
#'   accepted)
#' @param to name of destination addresses in a data frame (vector
#'   accepted)
#' @param output amount of output
#' @param mode driving, bicycling, or walking
#' @param messaging turn messaging on/off
#' @param sensor whether or not the geocoding request comes from a
#'   device with a location sensor
#' @param language language
#' @param departure_time number
#' @param traffic_model
#' @param override_limit override the current query count
#'   (.GoogleDistQueryCount)
#' @return a data frame (output="simple") or all of the geocoded
#'   information (output="all")
#' @author David Kahle \email{david.kahle@@gmail.com}
#' @details if parameters from and to are specified as geographic
#'   coordinates, they are reverse geocoded with revgeocode.  note
#'   that the google maps api limits to 2500 element queries a day.
#' @seealso
#' \url{http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/}
#'
#' @export
#' @examples
#'
#' \dontrun{ online queries draw R CMD check times
#'
#' mapdist("waco, texas", "houston, texas")
#'
#' from <- c("houston, texas", "dallas")
#' to <- "waco, texas"
#' mapdist(from, to)
#' mapdist(from, to, mode = "bicycling")
#' mapdist(from, to, mode = "walking")
#'
#' from <- c("houston", "houston", "dallas")
#' to <- c("waco, texas", "san antonio", "houston")
#' mapdist(from, to)
#'
#'
#' # geographic coordinates are accepted as well
#' (wh <- as.numeric(geocode("the white house, dc")))
#' (lm <- as.numeric(geocode("lincoln memorial washington dc")))
#' mapdist(wh, lm, mode = "walking")
#' distQueryCheck()
#'
#' }
#'
mapdist <- function(from, to, mode =     c("driving","walking","bicycling"),
                output = c("simple","all"), messaging = FALSE, sensor =     FALSE,
                language = "en-EN",     departure_time='1464926400',traffic_model= "optimistic", override_limit =     FALSE, key)
{

  message("by using this function you are agreeing to the terms at :")
  message("http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/\n")

  # check parameters
  if(is.numeric(from) && length(from) == 2) from <- revgeocode(from)
  stopifnot(is.character(from))
  if(is.numeric(to) && length(to) == 2) to <- revgeocode(to)
  stopifnot(is.character(to))
  from_to_df <- data.frame(from = from, to = to, stringsAsFactors =     FALSE)
  origins <- from_to_df$from
  destinations <- from_to_df$to # this ensures # from = # to
  mode <- match.arg(mode)
  output <- match.arg(output)
  stopifnot(is.logical(messaging))
  stopifnot(is.logical(sensor))


  getdists <- function(df){

# format url
origin <- df$from[1]
origin <- gsub(",", "", origin)
origin <- gsub(" ", "+", origin)
origin <- paste("origins=", origin, sep = "")
destinations <- df$to
destinations <- gsub(",", "", destinations)
destinations <- gsub(" ", "+", destinations)
destinations <- paste("destinations=", paste(destinations, collapse =     "|"), sep = "")
mode4url <- paste("mode=", mode, sep = "")
lang4url <- paste("language=", language, sep = "")
departure4url <- paste("departure_time=", departure_time, sep = "")
trans4url <- paste("traffic_model=", traffic_model, sep="")
sensor4url <- paste("sensor=", tolower(as.character(sensor)), sep = "")
keyUrl <- paste("key=", key, sep = "")
posturl <- paste(origin, destinations, mode4url, trans4url, sensor4url,     keyUrl, sep = "&")
url_string <-     paste("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?",
                    posturl, sep = "")
url_string <- URLencode(url_string)


# check if query is too long
if(nchar(url_string) >= 2048){
  n <- nrow(df)
  half_df <- floor(n/2)
  return(
    rbind(
      getdists(df[half_df,]),
      getdists(df[(half_df+1):n,])
    )
  )
}

# check/update google query limit
check_dist_query_limit(url_string, elems = nrow(df),
                       override = override_limit, messaging =     messaging)


# distance lookup
if(messaging) message("trying url ", url_string)
connect <- url(url_string)
tree <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(connect), collapse = ""))
close(connect)

# message user
message(paste0("Information from URL : ", url_string))

# label destinations - first check if all were found
if(length(df$to) != length(tree$destination_addresses)){
  message("matching was not perfect, returning what was found.")
  names( tree$rows[[c(1,1)]] ) <- tree$destination_addresses
  output <<- "all"
  # stringdist::amatch(df$to, tree$destination_addresses, maxDist = 10)
} else {
  names( tree$rows[[c(1,1)]] ) <- df$to
}

    # return
    tree$rows[[c(1,1)]]
  }

  out <- dlply(from_to_df, "from", getdists)

  # return all
  if(output == "all") return(out)



  # format output
  out <-
ldply(out, function(oneFromList){
  ldply(oneFromList, function(oneToList){
    data.frame(
      m = oneToList$distance$value,
      km = oneToList$distance$value/1000,
      miles = 0.0006214 * oneToList$distance$value,
      seconds = oneToList$duration$value,
      minutes = oneToList$duration$value / 60,
      hours = oneToList$duration$value / 3600
    )
  })
    })

  names(out) <- c("from", "to", names(out)[3:ncol(out)])

  # "simple" return
  suppressMessages(join(from_to_df, out))
}




check_dist_query_limit <- function(url_string, elems, override,     messaging){
  .GoogleDistQueryCount <- NULL; rm(.GoogleDistQueryCount); # R CMD     check trick

  if(exists(".GoogleDistQueryCount", .GlobalEnv)){

    .GoogleDistQueryCount <<-
      subset(.GoogleDistQueryCount, time >= Sys.time() - 24*60*60)

    # 2500 per 24 hours
    if(sum(.GoogleDistQueryCount$elements) + elems > 2500){
  message("query max exceeded, see ?mapdist.  current total = ",
          sum(.GoogleDistQueryCount$elements))
  if(!override) stop("google query limit exceeded.", call. = FALSE)
}

# 100 per 10 seconds
if(with(.GoogleDistQueryCount,
        sum(elements[time >= Sys.time() - 10]) + elems > 100
)){
  if(messaging) message("waiting 10 seconds for another 100     queries...", appendLF=F)
  Sys.sleep(10) # can do better
  if(messaging) message(" done")
}

# append to .GoogleDistQueryCount
.GoogleDistQueryCount <<- rbind(.GoogleDistQueryCount,
                                data.frame(time = Sys.time(),  url =     url_string,
                                               elements = elems,         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    )


  } else {

    .GoogleDistQueryCount <<-
  data.frame(time = Sys.time(),  url = url_string,
             elements = elems, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  }
}



#' Check Google Maps Distance Matrix API query limit
#'
#' Check Google Maps Distance Matrix API query limit
#'
#' @return a data frame
#' @author David Kahle \email{david.kahle@@gmail.com}
#' @seealso         \url{http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/}
#' @export
#' @examples
#' distQueryCheck()
distQueryCheck <- function(){
  .GoogleDistQueryCount <- NULL; rm(.GoogleDistQueryCount); # R CMD     check trick
  if(exists(".GoogleDistQueryCount", .GlobalEnv)){
    remaining <- 2500-sum(
      subset(.GoogleDistQueryCount, time >= Sys.time() -     24*60*60)$elements
)
message(remaining, " distance queries remaining.")
  } else {
    remaining <- 2500
    message(remaining, " distance queries remaining.")
  }
  invisible(remaining)
}
```

My data looks like this:

```
dput(X11)

structure(list(pickup = c("40.774135%2C-73.8749", "40.773988%2C-73.87485", 
"40.646821%2C-73.789771", "40.774079%2C-73.87462", "40.645691%2C-73.776686", 
"40.645434%2C-73.776758", "40.773917%2C-73.872989", "40.641596%2C-73.787964", 
"40.773691%2C-73.870689", "40.773579%2C-73.870659"), dropoff = c("40.758691%2C-73.961359", 
"40.786066%2C-73.971041", "40.731959%2C-74.009028", "40.736534%2C-74.008318", 
"40.759087%2C-73.960889", "40.757562%2C-73.960927", "40.765958%2C-73.94621", 
"40.783832%2C-73.972058", "40.75586%2C-73.96334", "40.783067%2C-73.984085"
)), .Names = c("pickup", "dropoff"), row.names = c("1002", "10283", 
"10629", "896515", "12312", "741575", "40637", "40864", "47772", 
"47952"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written the package [**googleway**](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) to access google maps API where you can specify your token key, and various other parameters (including departure time and mode)

For example

```
library(googleway)
key <- "your_api_key"

google_distance(origins = list("houston", "Dallas"),
                destinations = list("waco, Texas", "San Antonio"),
                key = key,
                mode = "transit",
                departure_time = as.POSIXct("2016-06-30"),
                simplify = FALSE)  ## use simplify = T to simplify to a data.frame


[[1] "{"                                                                              
[2] "   \"destination_addresses\" : [ \"Waco, TX, USA\", \"San Antonio, TX, USA\" ],"
[3] "   \"origin_addresses\" : [ \"Houston, TX, USA\", \"Dallas, TX, USA\" ],"       
[4] "   \"rows\" : ["                                                                
[5] "      {"                                                                        
[6] "         \"elements\" : ["                                                      
[7] "            {"                                                                  
[8] "               \"status\" : \"ZERO_RESULTS\""                                   
[9] "            },"                                                                 
[10] "            {"                                                                  
[11] "               \"distance\" : {"                                                
[12] "                  \"text\" : \"325 km\","                                       
[13] "                  \"value\" : 325079"                                           
[14] "               },"                                                              
[15] "               \"duration\" : {"                                                
[16] "                  \"text\" : \"4 hours 5 mins\","                               
[17] "                  \"value\" : 14693"                                            
[18] "               },"                                                              
[19] "               \"status\" : \"OK\"" 
... etc
```